# Nested Array to HTML archive. Sample code included

Tags: php, html

I've generated an array of dates. Here is a quick sample

```
Array
(
[2013] => Array
    (
        [Feb] => 2013
        [Jan] => 2013
    )

[2012] => Array
    (
        [Oct] => 2012
        [Jun] => 2012
        [May] => 2012
    )

)
```

Sample code:

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'post', ));
#       $i=1;
print '<pre>';
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    #       $post_results[$post->ID][month] = get_the_time('m', $post->ID);
    #       $post_results[$post->ID][year]  = get_the_time('Y', $post->ID);
    $year = get_the_time('Y', $post -> ID);
    $month = get_the_time('M', $post -> ID);
    $post_results[$year][$month] = get_the_time('Y', $post -> ID);
    #       echo "$i. Post ID: "  .$post->ID." - " .get_the_time('Y-m-d', $post->ID)."<br/>";
    #       $i++;
}

foreach ($post_results as $key => $value) {
    echo "Month: " . $key . " Year: " . $value . "<br/>";
}

print_r($post_results);
print '</pre>';
?>
```

I'd like to list all dates in the same format as this webpage http://www.smartpassiveincome.com/archives/

What I need is help getting my array to separate values like what you see above. I can do the linking part myself, I just need the data pulled into easy to use variables for me.

For example, I'd like to say "For each year, get all the months listed, then type out `<td>$year</td><td>$month</td>` then move on to the previous year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think you need, his is one way to achieve the following:

2013 | Feb | Jan
2012 | Oct | Jun | May

**Original:**

```
$arrYears = array(2013=>array("Feb"=>2013, "Jan"=>2013), 2012=>array("Oct"=>2013, "Jun"=>2013, "May"=>2013));
        foreach($arrYears as $strYear=>$arrMonths) {
            echo $strYear;
            // This is our logic for each year
            foreach($arrMonths as $strMonth=>$strYear2) {
                echo " | ".$strMonth;
            }
            echo "<br />";
        }
```

**Edit: Put months in a nested list**

```
 $arrYears = array(
                 2013=>array("Feb"=>2013, "Jan"=>2013),
                 2012=>array("Oct"=>2013, "Jun"=>2013, "May"=>2013)
              );

 echo "<ul>";
     foreach($arrYears as $strYear=>$arrMonths) {
         echo "<li>";
             echo $strYear;
             echo "<ul>";

                foreach($arrMonths as $strMonth=>$strYear2) {
                    echo "<li><a href='#'>".$strMonth."</a></li>";
                }

             echo "</ul>";
         echo "</li>";
     }
 echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you what you need. Just change `$currentDate` to be a timestamp for whatever date you want to start from.

```
$currentDate = strtotime('January 1st, 2000');
$newestDate = strtotime(date('Y-m-01'));
$yearMonthArray = array();

while ($currentDate <= $newestDate) {
    if (!array_key_exists($year = date('Y', $currentDate), $yearMonthArray)) {
        $yearMonthArray[$year] = array();
    }

    $yearMonthArray[$year][] = date('M', $currentDate);

    $currentDate = strtotime('next month', $currentDate);
}

var_dump($yearMonthArray);
```

Edit: This just gets you all year/month combinations. You should be able to use this example combined with your code to get something that shows only months with posts.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself, here is my new code

```
$posts = get_posts(
    array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post',
    )
);
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $year = get_the_time('Y', $post->ID);
    $month = get_the_time('M', $post->ID);
    $post_results[$year][$month]  = $month;
}

foreach ($post_results as $key => $value) { 
    echo "<b>"  .$key."</b> ";

    foreach ($value as $sub_key => $sub_value) { 
        echo $sub_key." ";
    }
    echo "<br/>";

}
```